# datatables: how to repopulate table after data changed?

Tags: datatable, datatables

My goal is to repopulate/redraw/refresh table after aaData:'data' changed:

```
$(tableid).dataTable({
        "aaData": data,
        "destroy": true,
        "aoColumns": columns
  });
```

I suceed with some tricky:

```
$(tableid).dataTable().fnClearTable();
$(tableid).dataTable().fnDestroy();
$(tableid).dataTable({
            "aaData": data,
            "destroy": true,
            "aoColumns": columns
      });
```

which looks very horrible. I guess there must be a cleaner way to do that ?

Comment: What version of datatables are you using?

Comment: the latest one.

Comment: `$(tableid).dataTable().fnClearTable()` and `$(tableid).dataTable().fnDestroy()` is redundant. All you need is `destroy: true` in each end every (re)initialisation of the table.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this struggle with datatables also.

My solution:

*var data = [json loaded with ajax]*

```
function loadTable(data){

    if($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#testsListTable')){

        if(data.testRunReports.length == 0)
            $('#testsListTable').dataTable().fnClearTable();
        else
            $('#testsListTable').dataTable().fnAddData(data);

        return;
    }

    $('#testsListTable').DataTable({
         data: data,

...
```